# Connecting to the HTTPS using self signed SSL certificate

Tags: iphone, ssl, certificate, asihttprequest

I've a problem connecting to the server using SSL. I'm using ASIHTTPRequest.

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://server:port"]];
//[request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setTimeOutSeconds:10];

[request addRequestHeader:@"Host" value:@"server:port"];    
[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"text/json; charset=utf-8"];
```

Above gives me the "A connection failure occurred: SSL problem (possibly a bad/expired/self-signed certificate)". If I uncomment the line [request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO]; I get 404.

I know that that in the development environment the server uses the self-signed certificate, on production server the certificate is signed by "thawte".

So I emailed the certificate to myself, tap the attachement using Mail app on my device - it redirected me to the settings and I installted the certificate. Of course as it was self-signed it tells me that the certificate is not trusted, but it's the only problem with the certificate, it's not expired etc.

Now I do the same approach and I again receives either "A connection failure occurred: SSL problem (possibly a bad/expired/self-signed certificate)" or 404.

I've also added the certificate to my project and add following lines:

```
NSData* certData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cert" ofType:@"cer"]];

SecCertificateRef cert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, (CFDataRef)certData);
[request setClientCertificates:[NSArray arrayWithObject:(id)cert]];
```

but it doesn't change anything.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like the REST client addon for firefox to do the identical POST from a browser. To see what the site is really returning.  It just might be that a 404 is the correct response from the server for the specified URL and the invalid cert is just preventing the SSL negotiation from completing so you never see the error.

Comment: Could you recommend any good? Some of them says they won't work at Firefox 4.0b7. And btw I'm sure the API works exactly the same using http and https.

Comment: I haven't upgraded to FF 4 due to compatibility issues, so I don't know if 'REST Client' does or doesn't work with it.  The name of the addon is 'REST Client'. I've come of the opinion lately, that using self-signed certs in development is actually a waste of money.  On every project I've worked on using self-signed certs it has cost several hours of developer time to resolve issues with them.  I now recommend to my clients that they just pony up the couple hundred bucks for a real cert and eliminate another hurdle for developers.

Comment: If you have the private key of the cert, which you probably do since it's self signed, I believe you can configure WireShark to decrypt the SSL traffic.  That could help you find out exactly what's happening on your connection.

Comment: Everything was fine, sorry. The problem occured on the server and has been fixed by admin.